# Exception on NSData to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to convert NSData to NSString, and I'm getting a SIGABRT on this command

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It appears the exception is NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I inspect the NSData object in a breakpoint and it pops up with expected data.  Why on earth would a simple data conversion like this go so wrong?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us the complete, exact exception.

Comment: Are you sure that `theData` is really an `NSData` instance? Show where that is created.

Comment: print in console `po [theData class]` and confirm it is really NSData instance

Comment: We still need the complete and exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

You guys pointed me in the winning direction by questioning type of object ... I was extracting it from a dictionary and assumed it was an NSData object, but in reality it was *already* an NSString.  Ugh.  Thanks a lot!